# a:visited for docx files -- Color wont change in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-selectors, docx

I have a simple HTML, the links change color in Edge and Firefox, but not in IE and Chrome

In particular docx files are an issue, although it may be a more general issue with docx files

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link{
text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited{
color:pink;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active{
text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Below links open in the same tab</p>

<a href="https://www.smh.com.au">SMH</a>
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>
<a href="http://www.dhs.state.il.us/OneNetLibrary/27897/documents/Initiatives/IITAA/Sample-Document.docx">Docx</a>
<a href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">pdf</a>

<p>Below links open in the new tab</p>

<a href="https://www.news.com.au" target="_blank">News</a>
<a href="https://microsoft.com" target="_blank">Microsoft</a>
<a href="https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/docx/example.docx" target="_blank">Docx</a>
<a href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" target="_blank">pdf</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> Unvisited links are blue.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Hover over will underline the links.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Visited links are pink.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with docx (from ms-word) in the browser or in the html code?

Comment: The file extension is docx

Comment: Tested in IE11, FF, Edge, Chrome and Opera. It works fine with `a, a:link { text-decoration: none; } a:visited { color: pink; } a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: underline; }` I tedsted with the href to wikipedia. Btw. a:visited is not good practice, better not use it.